# Json to HttpContent using streams

Tags: c#, serialization, stream, json.net, httpclient

I have a class `MyData` which is Json serializable by using Json.Net `JsonSerializer.Serialize(TextWriter, object)`. I want to send this data (as json) to a web service via `HttpClient.PostAsync`.

Because converting the json to string and then sending it as `StringContent` is (probably) not performant, I want to do it with streams.

I found the class `StreamContent`, which takes a stream in its constructor. And serializing json into streams should be possible as well. So I tried this:

```
MyData data = ...; // already filled
string uri = ...;  // already filled
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms))
    using (JsonWriter jw = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(sw, data);
        ms.Flush();
        ms.Position = 0;
    }
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(uri, new StreamContent(ms)).Result;
}
```

But running this code gives me two exceptions in the line `HttpResponseMessage response = ...`:

1. HttpRequestException: Error when copying content into a stream.
2. ObjectDisposedException: Could not access closed stream.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 2):

If you serialize the object into a `MemoryStream`, the entire JSON data will be written in the buffer, so there is no significant performance benefit over just serializing into a string and using `StringContent`.

Comment: So I guess I should use a buffered stream?

Comment: A buffered stream is only a layer over another stream, so it's not going to be useful. In .NET Core 2.1, you can use [pipelines](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/07/09/system-io-pipelines-high-performance-io-in-net/). But that's really only going to make a difference for large JSON files (several megabytes) or for very hot paths.

Answer (score 1):

Your StremWriter disposes the memory stream before the request is sent, that is why you get the exceptions.
You can either move your using statements to be in the same scope as the MemoryStream, or use the StreamWriter's constructor that accepts a boolean parameter to leave the stream open after the writer is disposed.

[StreamWriter constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712853(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Unless you set the leaveOpen parameter to true, the StreamWriter object calls Dispose() on the provided Stream object when StreamWriter.Dispose is called.